# Plot polar data at a location on a map using pcolormesh and Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, polar-coordinates

I have arrays of theta, r and z, representing some data in polar coordinates at a known lat/lon point.

How can I display this data, using pcolormesh, on a Basemap map? Basically I want to overlay a standard polar pcolormesh plot at the origin where the data is coming from.

Comment: Do you want to plot on Earth disk or  just get a circle pcolormesh?

Comment: Well I want to plot it on whatever projection/map area i have created via Basemap (not necessarily the full Earth disk)